# Grid does not fill the whole window, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have written a UI for an Game of Life (Automation Theory) and the algorithm works just fine. I have also created a pop-up which will start first and where you can set the amount of rows and columns the game should have. This works also fine. Somehow my Grid only fills a small amount of the space in the window (Like it would only be in the left top cell of another Grid). I cannot work out why this is happening. Help would be much appreciated. I am aware that the code is quit complex and messy at this point. The GameCreation() Method is calling the popup window first. After that I declare some variables and my grid. Then I create rows and columns and button which I store in the grid as well. There are no errors or exceptions.

This is how the window looks like:

[image: Window]

```
private void GameCreation()
{
    //Pop-up Fenster aufrufen und eingaben in rowCount und colCount speichern

    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list = OptionsWindow();

    //Variablen deklarieren
    int nameNum = 1;
    int rowCount = list[0];
    int colCount = list[1];
    Button[,] buttons = new Button[rowCount, colCount];
    Grid MainGrid = new Grid();
    Window1.Content = MainGrid;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
        {
            // create Grid.RowDefinition and Grid.ColumnDefinition based on rowCount and colCount

            RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
            GridLengthConverter gridLengthConverter = new GridLengthConverter();
            row.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

            ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
            column.Width = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);

            // Button erstellen
            Button button = new Button
            {
                Name = "B" + nameNum,
                Background = Brushes.Gray,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                Padding = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)
            };
            button.Click += ChangeColor;
            //den Button zum Grid hinzufügen an der richtigen Stelle
            Grid.SetRow(button, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(button, j);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(button);
            //Button buttons[,] hinzufügen
            buttons[i, j] = button;
            nameNum++;

        }
        
    }

    //resetButton deklarieren
    Button resetButton = new()
    {
        Name = "resetButton",
        Background = Brushes.DodgerBlue,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
        Padding = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1),
        Content = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\myname\\source\\repos\\GameOfLife\\GameOfLifeApp\\ResetButton2.png"))
        }
    };
    resetButton.Click += Reset;
    Grid.SetRow(resetButton, rowCount);
    Grid.SetColumn(resetButton, 0);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(resetButton, 1);

    //StartButton deklarieren
    RowDefinition row2 = new RowDefinition();
    GridLengthConverter gridLengthConverter2 = new GridLengthConverter();
    row2.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter2.ConvertFrom("*");
    MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row2);
    Button startButton = new()
    {
        Name = "startButton",
        Background = Brushes.DodgerBlue,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
        Padding = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1),
        Content = "Start",
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Foreground = Brushes.White
    };
    startButton.Click += Start;
    Grid.SetRow(startButton, rowCount);
    Grid.SetColumn(startButton, 1);
    int colSpan = colCount - 2;
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(startButton, colSpan);

    //clearButton deklarieren
    Button clearButton = new()
    {
        Name = "clearButton",
        Background = Brushes.DodgerBlue,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
        Padding = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1),
        Content = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\myname\\source\\repos\\GameOfLife\\GameOfLifeApp\\ClearButton.png"))
        }
    };
    clearButton.Click += Clear;
    Grid.SetRow(clearButton, rowCount);
    Grid.SetColumn(clearButton, colCount - 1);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(clearButton, 1);

    //Button Array richtig besetzen
    int[,] startArray = new int[rowCount, colCount];
    int rowLength = startArray.GetLength(0);
    int colLength = startArray.GetLength(1);
    startArray = Phasen.StartArray(startArray);
    buttons = TranslatetoButtonArray(startArray, buttons, rowLength, colLength);

    //Funktionsbutton MainGrid hinzufügen
    MainGrid.Children.Add(startButton);
    MainGrid.Children.Add(clearButton);
    MainGrid.Children.Add(resetButton);
}
```

I have tried setting the heigth and width of the Grid to auto but that doesnt change anything. When i had a fix amount of buttons and declared the Grid aswell as the buttons in the .xaml file there was no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think you have this issue is because your code runs after measure and arrange have been done for your window.

I'm not sure why adding the grid doesn't force that again but I have a suggestion could make your problem go away.

Add

```
 Window1.InvalidateVisual();
```

To the end of your code.

If that still doesn't work then try instead:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() =>
{
     Window1.InvalidateVisual(); 
}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Still no joy then try not showing whatever this popup is. Maybe you're showing that as modal.

This approach of building everything out in code is inadvisable. Datatemplating is perfectly capable of working fast enough for basic games.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your thoughts! The solution was very simple in the end. I created the GridRowDefinitions and the GridColumnDefinitions inside both for loops. This way i created as many Rows and Columns as buttons. When i turned on the Gridlines i saw that the Grid is actually filling the whole Window. I solved the problem by putting the code for the Row and Column Creation outside the for loops.